# error while executing gem (Errno::EACCES)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

After trying to update Ruby gems 2.1.0, by running the command "gem update --system" i am getting an error message:

```
    Updating rubygems-update
    Successfully installed rubygems-update-2.4.8
    Installing RubyGems 2.4.8
    ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/gauntlet_rubygems.rb
    Brians-MacBook-Pro% RROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    zsh: unknown sort specifier
```

Can someone please help me to fix this issue? Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the command as super user:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

see if that works for you.

Comment: @bcmakesiteasy To know how accepting answer works, please see this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work